# Можно ли сократить запись проверки на null и undefined

Tags: javascript, if

Интересно, можно ли сократить данную запись? Чтобы `this.value !==` ещё раз не повторялся?

```
this.value !== null && this.value !== undefined
```

Comment: А это у вас где стоит? в if? Все зависит от решаемой задачи

Comment: @SwaD Да, в if стоит.

Comment: Можно так: `const p = v => v !== null && v !== undefined;`. В коде будет `p(this.value)` - довольно компактно.

Comment: при проверки на равенство `null` и `undefined` - эквивалентны, поэтому достаточно написать `this.value != null` не нужно дублировать для `undefined`, либо наоборот `this.value != undefined` и не нужна проверка на `null`

Comment: @Grundy однако это не так. Проверки на **null** и **undefined** дают разный результат. Попробуй сам, вот сделал для тебя [тесты в песочниче](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/suspicious-voice-q2vyyl) (см консоль)

Comment: @SwaD ты невнимательно читаешь комментарий. Обрати внимание какой оператор использую я и какой у тебя

Comment: не строгое равенство... я уже отвык от него

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать оператор нулевого слияния **??**

> ВАЖНО! Пример ниже будет работать правильно, только в том случае, когда `this.value` **не может** быть **пустой строкой**, **нулем** или **false**. Во всех остальных случаях оператор нулевого слияния можно использовать в конструкции `if`

```js
function test() {
  console.log(this.value)
  if (this.value ?? 0) {
    console.log('new', false)
  } else {
    console.log('new', true)
  }

  if (this.value !== null && this.value !== undefined) {
    console.log('old', false)
  } else {
    console.log('old', true)
  }

}

test.call({value: undefined})
test.call({value: null})
test.call({value: 1})
test.call({value: '1'})
test.call({value: true})
console.log('Не верный результат:')
test.call({value: ''})
test.call({value: 0})
test.call({value: false})
```

Оператор нулевого слияния проверяет, если слева значение `null` или `undefined` то возвращается то что справа, иначе, то что слева.

Если `this.value` будет 0, к примеру, то:
`Boolean(this.value ?? 0)` вернет `false`, т.к. `0` превращается в `false`
С пустой строкой и false аналогично